# Reconstructing an isomorphism of exact triangles in the homotopy cat. of a dg-cat. using a functorially induced isomorphism between cones

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, higher-category-theory, triangulated-categories, dg-categories

This question is strictly related to [this other one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/177848/reconstructing-a-morphism-of-exact-triangles-in-the-homotopy-cat-of-a-dg-cat-u).

Let $\mathcal A$ be a (strongly) pretriangulated dg-category over a field $k$. Let

[image]
<sub>(source: [presheaf.com](http://presheaf.com/cache/d86dhk341k582e6j252q2b3qn3v32.png))</sub>

be a diagram in $Z^0(\mathcal A)$, where the rows are pretriangles in $\mathcal A$. Assume that the diagram is commutative in $H^0(\mathcal A)$, and that $u,v,w$ are invertible in $H^0(\mathcal A)$ (they have an inverse up to homotopy). Then, is it true or false that I can find $u' : A \to A', v': B \to B'$ closed of degree 0, and $h': A \to B'$ of degree $-1$ with that $dh' = v'f - f'u'$, such that $[u] = [u'], [v]=[v']$ and $[w] = [C(u',v',h')]$ in $H^0(\mathcal A)$? Here $C(u',v',h')$ denotes the morphism $C(f) \to C(f')$ functorially induced by the triple $(u',v',h')$.

I believe the answer is *no* even in this case where we consider isomorphisms in $H^0(\mathcal A)$, but perhaps we need a different counterexample as [the one given](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/177848/reconstructing-a-morphism-of-exact-triangles-in-the-homotopy-cat-of-a-dg-cat-u/177873#177873) in the other discussion.